# count number of div by id after dynamically adding more div by sam id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on page load i have following div

```
<div id="row_log">......</div>
```

at this stage if i do `console.log($('#row_log').length);` then i get response as 1 which is correct.

however, i have button to clone the same div, which works fine. So if the button was clicked thrice, i would now have :

```
<div id="row_log">.....</div> original div
<div id="row_log">.....</div> cloned div
<div id="row_log">.....</div> cloned div
<div id="row_log">.....</div> cloned div
```

yet `console.log($('#row_log').length);` would still show as 1 instead of 4

Comment: Use `class` attribute instead of `id` when you want to name and identify elements in repetition.

Comment: IDs have to be **unique** per document

Comment: @omerowitz : if would really appreciate if you would mention the same thing as answer, that way, i would be able to up-vote and select your suggestion as the right answer

Comment: @IrfanHarun you'd be better off just deleting the question as it's a duplicate which has been asked many times before

Comment: @IrfanHarun I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
Use `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Important points :
1. Id's must be unique.
2. In case of duplicate id's JavaScript will always get the first element for you, hence the length 1.

If you are just building a dynamic list or something, you can instead use a class.

......
 And then do  document.getElementsByClassName(className)